# System UI constantly crashes after installing incompatible theme on CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, system, themes

I installed a theme on CyanogenMod 13 that is incompatible. Now my **System UI** keeps crashing.

I can't find it with the file manager. How can I delete the theme?

Is there any way I could fix this without reinstalling or factory resetting?

Comment: This [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/cm12-theme-engine-howto-recover-boot-t3021505) suggests removing the 'theme' folder from /data/system if you have a custom recovery installed. I haven't tested this.

Comment: Delete the folder in `/data/app/incompatible_theme/` and `/data/data/incompatible_theme/` mentioned [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/118706-cm13-themes-unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped/#entry563991). CM Stock theme will be restored after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm still on CM12.1, [I can relate to you](http://www.enrepublic.com/2015/01/how-to-fix-cm-12-system-ui-crash.html).

Reboot to Safe Mode.
Go to *Settings > Apps > (Your Theme)*.
Uninstall it.

Hope this answers your question.